# component can't find provider from lazy-loaded module

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a lazy-loaded module which has one service and one component.

I would like to use the service in that component but I get:

```
Error: No provider for EventService!
```

The module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { EventRoutingModule } from './event-routing.module';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { EventListModule } from './../event-list/event-list.module';

import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';

import { EventComponent } from './event.component';
import { EventService } from './event.service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        EventRoutingModule,
        EventListModule
    ],
    declarations: [EventComponent]
})

export class EventModule {

    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: EventModule,
            providers: [EventService]
        };
    }

}
```

the component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EventService } from './event.service';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './event.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./event.component.scss']
})
export class EventComponent implements OnInit {


    private eventService: EventService;

    constructor(eventService: EventService) {
        this.eventService = eventService;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.eventService.getEvents().subscribe(data => console.log(data), error => console.log(error));
    }

}
```

the service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AuthHttp } from 'angular2-jwt';

@Injectable()
export class EventService {
    private static readonly URL = 'http://localhost:3000/api/events';

    constructor(private authHttp: AuthHttp) { }

    public getEvents() {

        return this.authHttp.get(EventService.URL);
    }

}
```

I have looked at a couple of posts here but havent been able to get a solution from them.

I know providers in lazy-loaded modules are module-scoped and lazy-loaded modules have their own dependency tree.

But it must be possible to inject the provider into the component, mustn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define how you provide your service.

You can define how it is provided at the **module level**:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        EventRoutingModule,
        EventListModule
    ],
    declarations: [EventComponent],
    providers: [EventService]
})
export class EventModule { ... }
```

This means that one `EventService` instance will be available for the whole module.

Or at the **component level**:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './event.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./event.component.scss'],
    providers [EventService]
})
export class EventComponent implements OnInit { ... }
```

This means that one `EventService` instance will be available for each component instance. This is due to the hierarchical injectors feature. The component defines its own injector which can hold its own instances that are being made available to its children.

**`[EventService]`** is equivalent to `[ { provide: EventService, useClass: EventService }]`. Which means that the key used to inject the dependency is `EventService` and the instance is being constructed by using the `EventService` constructor.

Comment: why is it not working with forRoot? I thought in case of lazy-loaded modules, you should use forRoot?

Comment: `forRoot()` is for configuring the routes at root level. `forChildren()` is good when you are splitting routing configuration as per-module basis. Usually is recommended for each module to have a separate module that configures the routing. That corresponding module that configures the routing will use `forChildren()`. On the other side, the routing `loadChildren` property can be used to load a module async when a route is reached.

Comment: Therefore, in your case, you have `EventModule`, you can have a separate `EventRoutingModule` module which does `forChildren()` in order to load routing configuration when the module will be loaded.

Comment: Thanks!! Helped me a lot!